# How edit languages information in product page in app store?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

This question may be very simple,but really I have searched a lot and didn't get result.
I published app in app store one month ago.My app supports 3 languages:English,Russian and Azerbaijanian.But I cannot add this feature in product page.Because I cannot find a way to edit Information part of product page.
For detailed explanation I attach image:
[image]

Comment: How did you add multilingual support? Are your 3 languages listed in the project’s info panel under the localization section in Xcode?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102826/how-to-change-appstore-language

Answer (score 1):

You can update meta data while the time of uploading new build. Once app goes into sale you can't change meta data. So, you have to upload new build for review before submit into review you can change meta data in **iTunes Connect**. Upload new version of your app and change meta data

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace your app with a new version:

> **Important:** You can manage languages only when the app status is editable
>
> 1. From the homepage, click My Apps and choose the app you want to localize.
>    The App Store page opens with App Information selected.
> 2. In the upper-right corner, click the primary language to display the language >pop-up menu.
> 3. Below Not Localized, hover over the language (and locale) you want to add, then click the Add button (+) that appears.
> 4. Enter the app name and privacy policy URL for the language or locale, then in the upper-right corner, click Save.
>
> Full description: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deve6f78a8e2

[image]

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation.I'll try and share result here with you